# Why i get this Error "An error occured while executing doInBackground()" .where i am wrong?

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

Why am I getting this Error

> An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Where am I wrong? LogCat is shown below

Here's my **LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static EditText username_edit_text;
    private static Button login_button;
    private static RadioGroup lang_group;
    RadioButton mar_radio_button;
    RadioButton eng_radio_button;
    TextView tv;
    String lang = "en";
    private Locale myLocale;
    Resources res;
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private final String URL = "http://My_server_ip/MobileLDAP/Service.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/OMS_Authenticate_Crew";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "OMS_Authenticate_Crew";
    private static String username;
    private static String resultm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        final ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector();
        username_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_UserName);
        login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_login);
        lang_group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioType);
        mar_radio_button = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioMar);
        eng_radio_button = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioEng);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        res = getResources();
        final Locale locale = res.getConfiguration().locale;
        lang_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                        if (locale.getLanguage().equals("mr")) {
                            mar_radio_button.setEnabled(false);
                            if (eng_radio_button.isChecked()) {
                                lang = "en";
                                setLocale(lang);
                            }
                        } else {
                            eng_radio_button.setEnabled(false);
                            if (mar_radio_button.isChecked()) {
                                lang = "mr";
                                setLocale(lang);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                username = username_edit_text.getText().toString();
                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void isAuthenticate(String Payroll_no) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo Payroll_info = new PropertyInfo();
        Payroll_info.setName("Payroll_no");
        Payroll_info.setValue(Payroll_no);
        Payroll_info.setType(double.class);
        request.addProperty(Payroll_info);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resultm = response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resultm = e.toString();
        }
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            isAuthenticate(username);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            tv.setText(resultm);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }

    public void setLocale(String lang) {
        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CommonPref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I'm not doing any UI work in doInBackGround function but I still get this error.

LogCat:

```
09-26 02:20:32.209 27677-27897/com.gis.reliance.customercomplaintreports E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.gis.reliance.customercomplaintreports, PID: 27677
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope
at com.gis.reliance.customercomplaintreports.activity.LoginActivity.isAuthenticate(LoginActivity.java:141)
at com.gis.reliance.customercomplaintreports.activity.LoginActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:160)
at com.gis.reliance.customercomplaintreports.activity.LoginActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:157)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Three votes to close as "off-topic"? Really? Maybe some people shouldn't have the power to vote close as this is a perfectly fine question, and in no way is it off-topic.

Comment: @ShadowGod - it isn't a [mcve]. The error is with the `isAuthenticate` method. The setup around calling the method isn't completely necessary

Comment: @YogeshKadam in the `catch` of `isAuthenticate`, please print the stacktrace of the exception instead of assigning it to `resultm`

Comment: @cricket_007  no this is not the problem here ,still error

Comment: Well, we don't know that. You are ignoring that exception there. Your error is in that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application run-time JVM and dependent lib JVM versions **should not differ.**

Comment: I am setting The value of username  in Button Click Method Nut it Still gives Error

Comment: That variable is set in the click listener before the AsyncTask is executed

Comment: @cricket_007 Still Error

Comment: Thanks for answers, Changing the  ksoap library version fix this

Comment: @YogeshKadam Glad it helped.  Please do consider upvoting this answer :) . Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean by this? How do you know the JVM version is different based on the information given?

Comment: @cricket_007 Initially it felt the real culprit was that authenticate method. But that was possible only if his **username** was corrupt. So incase that was not the case only thing left was his dependent library. As oracle docs mention [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html) that it is probably due to internal **inconsistency** the only **inconsistency** that I could guess was different JVM versions due to using old lib version. Hence, I asked him to make sure even that is alright. Logcat says error: org/ksoap2.. so **inconsistency** was somewhere in lib